# array_search Boolean return values

Tags: php

I have been struggling with array_search for a bit and although I think I understand it now, I just want to make absolutely sure I understand the logic behind the way my code is executing.

I am trying to write a function that will add an element to an array if it is not in the array to begin with, and remove it if it is. Simple, right?

```
$k = array_search($needle, $haystack)
if ( $k === FALSE ) {
    $haystack[] = $needle;
} else {
    unset($haystack[$k]);
}
```

Is this the most efficient way to write this? It seems like there should be a way to assign the value of $k and at the same time check whether its value is FALSE or anything else (including 0)?

Comment: Looks good apart from the missing `;` on first line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shorten your code this way:

```
if (($k = array_search($needle, $haystack)) === FALSE) {
    $haystack[] = $needle;
} else {
    unset($haystack[$k]);
}
```

The first line of code performs the search, stores the returned value in $k, and checks if this value is exactly equal to FALSE or not.

Documentation: [array_search](http://php.net/array_search)

Comment: @cpattersonv1 `$k` is always set. Either with false if `$needle` is not found, or with a key value to indicate where to find `$needle` in `$haystack` array. [Check the manual page for array_search](http://php.net/array_search) for more information.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 The parentheses are there for a good reason. I don't see why you would want to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine but you can do it this way:-

```
if (($k = array_search($needle, $haystack)) == FALSE) 
{
$haystack[] = $needle;
} 
else 
{
unset($haystack[$k]);
}
```

Comment: No he's missing the triple equals sign. This won't work if the matched element has a key of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of wrapping it with a function so you can reuse it, what you have works well. Most of the other examples are just rewriting what you've written already.

```
<?php
$haystack = array(
'5','6','7',
);

$needles = array('3','4','2','7');
print_r($haystack);


function checker($needle,$haystack){
    $k = array_search($needle, $haystack);
    if ( $k === FALSE ) {
        $haystack[] = $needle;
    } else {
        unset($haystack[$k]);
    }
    return $haystack;
}


foreach($needles as $value){
    $haystack = checker($value,$haystack);
    print_r($haystack);

}



?>
```